# Can't stop getting Windows Update error 0x80073712 despite running every fix I can find On Windows 10 21h2 X64

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

Attempting to update my computer and getting the listed error on the listed update (2022-04 Cumulative Update for Windows 10 Version 21h2 for X64).

I tried everything on the guides that are repeated everywhere, though this is the most comprehensive that contains all the ones I tried: https://www.ubackup.com/windows-10/reset-windows-update-windows-10-1021.html (though I didn't do the rollback ones).

The short version is:

- Virus scan
- SFC /scannow
- DISM checkhelth etc
- Windows update reset
- Windows update troubleshooter
- Manual download and install of updates (SSU 1904.1161, KB5012599 (the one that won't install), and KB5011831 (the next optional quality update)) from the win10 catalogue. The updater seems to work then gives me a super-unhelpful "some updates weren't isntalled" message).

In theory I could fix this by restoring my Win10 files, but all my programs would have to be reinstalled and configured which would suck. I could upgrade to Win11, but that's buggy and could also suck. I really don't know what else to do, but those can't be my only choices can they?

Windows update log here: https://pastebin.com/5N7m6QVt

Comment: Post your Windows Update log otherwise we cannot help.  Simplest solution to this problem is probably going to be an in-place repair install using a 21H2 ISO.

Comment: I figured out how to generate and post the logs. They are here: https://pastebin.com/5N7m6QVt